# Mapping enums to types

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++17

I have two unrelated types: `Object` and `Unrelated` implementing the same basic interface `Interface` (for storing in the same container).

I have an enum class that basically maps these types to enums

```
enum class TypeEnum {
    TYPE_OBJECT,
    TYPE_UNRELATED,
};
```

I have a reading method, that basically down-casts from the Interface to an implementation class

```
template<typename DATA>
const DATA& Read(const Container<Interface>& container, TypeEnum type);
```

Is it possible to automate the code, such that (this is a pseudo code)

```
switch(type_enum) {
    case TYPE_OBJECT:
        return Read<Object>(container, type_enum);
    case TYPE_UNRELATED:
        return Read<Unrelated>(container, type_enum);
}
```

can be made into a one liner?

NB. I have a bunch of enum values around 50 and a number of places i want to use this idiom.

In my want-to-have way, I would prefer something aka

```
template<TypeName>
struct TypePicker;

template<>
struct TypePicker<TYPE_OBJECT> {
    typedef Object underlying_type;
};

template<>
struct TypePicker<TYPE_UNRELATED> {
    typedef Unrelated underlying_type;
};
```

and then

```
return Read<TypePicker<type_enum>::underlying_type>(container, type_enum);
```

However, type_enum is only known at run-time.

Comment: Why isn't `Read` just a virtual method?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, cause in reality these are many more methods, and `Object` is basically a plain data type, that is not meant to engage in various activities of all the different processing stations, that use it.

Comment: This feels more like a design problem than a programming problem. Working around a flawed design is hard and will take time.

Comment: Looks like you need get familiar with visitor pattern: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2022/02/09/design-patterns-vs-design-principles-visitor/

Comment: How would you expect the return type to be? Since `std::variant` can't store reference

Comment: @Nimrod, I [suppose] const reference is what was meant by the original author to save expensive copies of the data. However, at the new code site I do want an independent copy, if it makes things easier.

Comment: @MarekR, I went over Wikipedia article, however, I don't quite get "how would a visitor know to produce a right down-casted object out of itself".

Comment: https://youtu.be/MdtYi0vvct0?t=1065

Comment: You need to have a switch-case or equivalent (i.e. a map) somewhere. Good news is, you only need it once. Wrap it in a function template that accepts an enum and an action to perform. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turn the reference into a copy to fit `std::variant`,

```cpp
// using std::type_identity for C++20 or later
template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

using VType = std::variant<type_identity<Object>,
                           type_identity<Unrelated>>;

using RType = std::variant<Object, Unrelated>;

static const std::map<TypeEnum, VType> dispatcher = {
    {TypeEnum::TYPE_OBJECT, type_identity<Object>{}},
    {TypeEnum::TYPE_UNRELATED, type_identity<Unrelated>{}}
};

auto foo(TypeEnum type_enum)
{
    Container<Interface> container;
    return std::visit([&](auto v) -> RType {
        return Read<typename decltype(v)::type>(container, type_enum);
    }, dispatcher.at(type_enum));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Wrj5GdjK)